# -[UIApplication openURL:] How long can NSURL be?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurl

Is there a limit to the length that `NSURL` can be for `-[UIApplication openURL:]`?

Comment: Apparently no hard limit, so just check a regular URL's max size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers (in short: to be totally safe, 2000 chars)

Answer (score 3):

The official answer, according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString%3a): As long as the URL conforms to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), you're OK.